# Service in Angular app is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this question has been answered before but honestly I can't make heads or tails of any of the answers in my program's context. My service looks like:

```
(function() {
angular
    .module('datingApp')
    .service('authentication', authentication);

authentication.$inject = ['$window'];
authentication.$inject = ['$http'];

function authentication($window, $http) {

    var saveToken = function(token) {
        $window.localStorage['token'] = token;
    };

    var getToken = function() {
        return $window.localStorage['token'];
    };

    var register = function($http, user) {
        return $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/users/register',
            data: user
        })
    };

    ...

    return {
        saveToken: saveToken,
        getToken: getToken,
        register: register
    }

}
```

All good, except when I try to use the register function in my controller "Cannot read property 'register' of undefined" pops up. None of the functions work, even a dummy function I wrote.

My controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('datingApp').component('signupForm', {
    templateUrl: '/public/templates/signup.html',
    controller: function signupCtrl($scope, authentication) {
    //using an immediate function to generate ages 18-99

    $scope.saveData = function(authentication) {
    ...

    authentication.register(x).then(function() { console.log("user saved") }, function() { console.log("failure") });
};
```

The error stack is this:

```
ypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined
at m.$scope.saveData (signup.form.component.js:72)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:1), <anonymous>:4:215)
at b (angular.js:15694)
at e (angular.js:25622)
at m.$eval (angular.js:17444)
at m.$apply (angular.js:17544)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:25627)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you importing Angular?

Comment: Yeah, and my service.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are overriding original injected service with local variable within `saveData()` function with the same name *authentication* which is then declared but undefined. So, just try to remove *authentication* variable from `saveData()` function:

```
angular.module('datingApp').component('signupForm', {
  templateUrl: '/public/templates/signup.html',
  controller: function signupCtrl($scope, authentication) {
  //using an immediate function to generate ages 18-99

  $scope.saveData = function() {
  ...

  authentication.register(x).then(function() { console.log("user saved") }, function() { console.log("failure") });
```

};

BTW: you can combine these 2 lines:

```
authentication.$inject = ['$window'];
authentication.$inject = ['$http'];
```

into one:

```
authentication.$inject = ['$window', '$http'];
```

Comment: Awesome tip about the 2 lines!

However, I actually had it like that before (with no *authentication* passed as an argument to the saveData function) and it gave me "$http is not a function". The stack trace refers to the register function in the services, which as far as I can tell is set up correctly, as is the .then callback in the controller.

Comment: Instead of *"you can combine these 2 lines"*, it's really *"you **must** combine these two lines"*

Comment: Good to know... it made no difference in the $http error, unfortunately.

Comment: @JohnB, can you please upload your code to plunker or fiddle, or at least post you entire component's code.

Comment: also, I think you have the same mistake in your service -> register function, you are overriding again injected $http service with function local variable called with the same name $http (I think this gave you "$http is not a function" message), just do not pass $http to the register function